# Select2 JQuery's AJAX Method from example is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I want to create a search input field using select2.js 4.0.5. I looked at the [select2 example](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax) and basically, want to learn by recreating them without using the template result (only return text).

However, I cannot make it work. This is the closest I can get: [myJSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcedbxvp/23/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function(params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },
      processResults: function(data, params) {
        // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
        // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
        // scrolling can be used
        params.page = params.page || 1;

        return {
          results: data.items,
          pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
          }
        };
      },
      cache: true
    }
  });
});
```

Even copying directly everything from the example does not work: [exampleJSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcedbxvp/25/).

I am still new to JS and Ajax. I'm sure that I'm missing something. Could someone please explain what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally get it running. Although I don't know how to fix the size of the search box: ([Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcedbxvp/50/))

**HTML**

```
<select class="js-data-example-ajax"></select>
```

**JS**

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function(params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },
      processResults: function(data) {
        return {
          results: data.items
        };
      },
      cache: false
    },
    templateResult: formatResult
  });

  function formatResult(result) {

    return result.full_name;
  };
```

Comment: The select adapts to the values included at the beginning. Since you load data via ajax it is initially empty. So you have to set width manually with style property or using a class.